# How to insert new rows and mark existing rows with no update and updated rows in SQL Server using merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure in SQL Server and implement an upsert such that it will move data from a staging table (a.k.a Source) to final table (a.k.a target) and mark rows which are new, updated, not updated or deleted every time a new batch of data comes in. I am using merge as explained [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/).

The problem is it is updating the rows that do not have any changes. My workflow is as follows:

1. Load data into source table
2. Call the stored procedure that will move data from `Source` to `Target` based on merge criteria

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[upsert_with_flag_2]
AS
    DECLARE @current_time AS datetime
    SET @current_time = GETDATE()

    MERGE [dbo].[employee] AS Target
    USING [dbo].[employee_staging] AS Source
          ON Source.[first_name] = Target.[first_name] 
             AND Source.[last_name] = Target.[last_name] 
             AND Source.[dob] = Target.[dob]

    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE 
            SET Target.[salary] = Source.[salary],
                Target.[current_address] = Source.[current_address],
                Target.[is_deleted] = 'Updated',
                Target.[processed_date] = @current_time

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target 
        THEN
            INSERT ([first_name], [last_name], 
                    [dob], [salary], 
                    [current_address], [is_deleted], 
                    [processed_date])
            VALUES (Source.[first_name], Source.[last_name],
                    Source.[dob], Source.[salary], 
                    Source.[current_address], 'New',
                    @current_time);

-- After doing upsert, check for rows whose processed date is less than current date but status is new or updated, These are
-- the rows which were not present in input file. Update there status to deleted
-- QUESTION: Should we change the processed date to current date for row's whose status is deleted?

UPDATE [dbo].[employee]
SET [is_deleted] = 'deleted'
WHERE ([is_deleted] = 'New' OR [is_deleted] = 'Updated') 
  AND [processed_date] < @current_time
```

After this I perform the following steps to load data and get output:

```
--Loading the initial data
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[employee_staging]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[employee_staging] ([first_name], 
                                      [last_name], 
                                      [dob], 
                                      [salary], 
                                      [current_address])
VALUES  ('John', 'Doe', '1995-04-28', 3000, 'Andra Pradesh'),
        ('Robert', 'Spenser', '1994-03-28', 1800, 'Madhya Pradesh'),
        ('Vikash', 'Sharma', '1996-12-20', 1400, 'Uttar Pradesh'),
        ('Anup', 'Soni', '1994-03-28', 1800, 'Delhi'),
        ('Prijan', 'Sonar', '1989-01-28', 3000, 'Himachal Pradesh')
GO

EXEC upsert_with_flag

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[employee]

--Loading the updated data
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[employee_staging]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[employee_staging] ([first_name], [last_name], 
                                       [dob], [salary], 
                                       [current_address])
VALUES ('Robert', 'Spenser', '1994-03-28', 2000, 'Madhya Pradesh'),
       ('Vikash', 'Sharma', '1996-12-20', 1400, 'Maharashtra'),
       ('Anup', 'Soni', '1994-03-28', 1800, 'Delhi'),
       ('Prijan', 'Sonar', '1989-01-28', 3000, 'Himachal Pradesh'),
       ('William', 'Beck', '1991-04-22', 3300, 'Karnataka'),
       ('Robert', 'Brownie', '1986-04-22', 5000, 'Assam')
```

[image]

Notice row number 4 and 5. There has been no change in the input row data for Anup still I get the [is_deleted] column as "Updated". I want it to be something like "Existing" or "No change".

Please help in making this possible. This upsert logic is a part of a big pipeline and we need the rows that are updated, new, not updated or deleted in the new file. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a case statement to the is_deleted field in the update to check whether anything has changed. Something like this:

```
MERGE [dbo].[employee] as Target
USING [dbo].[employee_stagging] as Source
ON Source.[first_name] = Target.[first_name] and
   Source.[last_name] = Target.[last_name] and
   Source.[dob] = Target.[dob]

WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET Target.[salary] = Source.[salary],
        Target.[current_address] = Source.[current_address],
        Target.[is_deleted] = CASE WHEN Source.salary = Target.salary
                                         AND Source.current_address = Target.current_address THEN 'No change'
                                   ELSE 'Updated'
                               END,
        Target.[processed_date] = @current_time

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target 
THEN
    INSERT ([first_name],
            [last_name],
            [dob],
            [salary], 
            [current_address], 
            [is_deleted],
            [processed_date])

    VALUES (Source.[first_name],
            Source.[last_name],
            Source.[dob],
            Source.[salary], 
            Source.[current_address], 
            'New',
            @current_time
            );
```

So if the update fields are identical to the staged data, it will update **is_deleted** to "No change", whereas if the update fields have changed it will update **is_deleted** to "Updated".

NOTE: This code is assuming salary and current_address are non-nullable fields (table definition for field is followed by NOT NULL). If there ARE nullable, then you should handle the null values by replacing the CASE statement with the following:

```
CASE WHEN (Source.salary = Target.salary
        OR Source.salary IS NULL
            AND Target.salary IS NULL)
    AND (Source.current_address = Target.current_address
        OR Source.current_address IS NULL
            AND Target.current_address IS NULL) THEN 'No change'
    ELSE 'Updated'
END
```

(Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

Comment: I am getting the following error: "An action of type 'WHEN MATCHED' cannot appear more than once in a 'UPDATE' clause of a MERGE statement." Seems cannot use when matched clause more than once.

Comment: Hello @Ashishsoni! Sorry, my bad :D I did know that! You can use WHEN MATCHED twice, but not if both are for an UPDATE statement. You can use it twice if one is for an UPDATE and the other is for DELETE (not what you want!). I've changed the code to include a basic CASE statement on your is_deleted field which should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a ton @sgtwickool This worked like a charm. Also thank you for considering the NULL cases. I got the logic that I needed.